# Trying to use a downloaded folder of Windows in Ubuntu on the same system

Tags: dual-boot, apt, server, virtualbox, virtualization

Trying to use a downloaded folder of Windows in Ubuntu on the same system.

Comment: That is not how this works. Find a how-to on-line, see how you get and if you have problems with commands on the Ubuntu end search AU for similar topics and in the case there is no answer ask here.